# jquery button slide toggle hidden content and image switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've trawled through previous posts by others with similar problems to mine and have managed to get to a certain point I am happy with, the only problem is I cannot get my image to be replaced dependent upon the open status of the hidden content.

I have multiple case studies, each with hidden content, when you click on any of the buttons it will slide the hidden content open for that particular case study and close any others that are open.

The page in its current state can be seen [here](http://www.v3cap.com/old/v3/service.html).

The HTML

```
<!-- BLOCK 1 -->
        <div class="serviceblock ten2 columns2">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/one.png" alt="1 - Personal Planning" />
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <h4>Personal planning</h4>
                <p>We achieve a more intimate understanding of our clients than anybody else, because we provide empathy and discretion, and devote more time to personal planning than anybody else. It is at this stage that we help our clients to express, and build their vision of the future with absolute clarity.</p>
            </div><!-- END TEXT -->
            <div class="hiddenTextWrapper fourteen2 columns2">
                <a href='#' class='toggleswitch'><img src='images/switchup.png' alt='' /></a>   
                <!-- HIDDEN TEXT -->
                <div class="hiddenText">
                    <h5>The Life Audit</h5>
                    <p>The Life Audit is a comprehensive and strictly confidential discussion of a client’s current circumstances, covering not just their existing banking relationships and assets, but all of the personal details that affect their wealth ambitions. These include their business interests, their family interests, the locations in which they operate, their world view and their risk appetite.</p>
                    <p>For our clients, the life audit has two main benefits: Firstly, it is so in-depth that it ensures that we, their advisors, understand them intimately enough to act as their proxy, leading to a more tailored service style and more fitting recommendations than they would experience anywhere else.</p>
                    <p>Secondly, the process of talking in a structured way about the things that matter most often helps the client to hone and refine their vision for the future, as well as to identify new goals and ambitions.</p>
                </div><!-- END HIDDEN TEXT -->
            </div><!-- END HIDDEN TEXT WRAPPER -->
        </div><!-- END SERVICEBLOCK -->
```

The Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var minusImg = "images/switchup.png";
var plusImg = "images/switchdown.png";

$(".toggleswitch").on('click', function () {
    var $ans = $(this).next(".hiddenText");
    $ans.slideToggle();
    $(".hiddenText").not($ans).slideUp();

    event.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
});

$("a.toggleswitch").click(function(){

   $(".hiddenText").slideToggle();

   var plusImg = "images/switchup.png";
   var minusImg = "images/switchdown.png";        
   $this = $(".toggleswitch img");            

   if( $this.attr('src') == plusImg ) { $this.attr('src', minusImg);} 
   else { $this.attr('src', plusImg); }

   });
```

Not very adept at Jquery no java, however very much willing to learn where I went wrong to correct that. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: why dont you use data-attribute to the <div class="hiddenText"> to store the state of the DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not selecting the image inside the scope so you get all images, also you're not initializing the variable with var and therefore it becomes a global variable. Try this:

```
$("a.toggleswitch").click(function(){

   $(".hiddenText").slideToggle();

   var plusImg = "images/switchup.png";
   var minusImg = "images/switchdown.png";        
   var $img = $(this).find("img");            

   if( $img.attr('src') === plusImg ) { 
     $img.attr('src', minusImg);
   } else { 
     $img.attr('src', plusImg); 
   }

});
```

Comment: fantastic Tosh, you really helped a lot there, I need to get a hang on global and localised variables better, as well as java's syntax.

Comment: In using the find function, it appears that when i click on one button and then the next the image remains the same on the previous state. I have updated the page to show what I mean.

Comment: This is because all hidden elements are toggled, but only s. You could also only toggle the hiddentext you click: $("a.toggleswitch").siblings(".hiddenText"). Are you can reset all images:   if( $img.attr('src') === plusImg ) { 
     $img.attr('src', minusImg);
   } else { 
     $("a.toggleswitch img").attr('src', plusImg); 
   }